# Linear inequalities system, closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the set: $$F_1:= \{ (x_1,x_2,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n} | \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i \geq b \}$$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

First I've proved that if $f(x): \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R^n} | f(x) \geq b \}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R^n}$. So i said: let $ f(x_1,x_2,..x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i$, then i want to prove that is continuous, but I don't know how to do it by definition.

Answer (score 0):

you know that if $h, k $ be to function which are continuous then $h+k$ is continuous. so it is enough to show that $f(x)=ax$ is continuous which is obvious($\delta\leq\frac{\epsilon}{\vert a\vert}$)

Comment: Thats true, thank you.

Comment: you are welcome :)